# Spark configuration tuning

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am running a spark program on a 31 node EMR cluster to transform some text files to parquet. Each run is processing several thousand 32 MB .gz text(~130MB uncompressed) files.  I am running in an issue where I am getting a java out of memory: heap space error.  I have been doing some research online on configurations, but none of them seem to work, all giving similar results. Had the following parameters:

```
[
    {
        "classification": "spark-env",
        "properties": {

        },
        "configurations": [
            {
                "classification": "export",
                "properties": {
                    "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/bin/python3"
                },
                "configurations": [

                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "classification": "spark-defaults",
        "properties": {
            "spark.driver.memory": "7G",
            "spark.yarn.scheduler.reporterThread.maxFailures": "5",
            "spark.driver.cores": "5",
            "spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead": "3072M",
            "spark.executor.heartbeatInterval": "60s",
            "spark.rdd.compress": "true",
            "spark.network.timeout": "800s",
            "spark.executor.cores": "5",
            "spark.executors.memory": "8G",
            "spark.shuffle.spill.compress": "true",
            "spark.shuffle.compress": "true",
            "spark.storage.level": "MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER",
            "spark.default.parallelism": "450",
            "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions": "-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'",
            "spark.executor.instances": "90",
            "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead": "1000M",
            "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled": "false",
            "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions": "-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'"
        },
        "configurations": [

        ]
    },
    {
        "classification": "yarn-site",
        "properties": {
            "yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled": "false",
            "yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled": "false"
        },
        "configurations": [

        ]
    }
]
```

The instances I am using have the following specs:

```
16 vCore, 
30 GiB memory, 
160 SSD GB storage
EBS Storage:32 GiB
```

My submit command is:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster s3://bucket/program.py
```

Does anyone see any obvious reason as to why I would be getting a heap space error?  Is it just the cluster size/specs, or is there something wrong with my configuration parameters?

Comment: you should increase Java heap memory or better containerize spark nodes since allocated driver memory, executor cores and available memory on node is not sufficient to be allocated.

spark.driver.memoryOverhead=driverMemory * 0.10, with minimum of 384mb

attributes needs to be updated:
spark.driver.memory 
spark.driver.memoryOverhead 

ref: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: So you think my overhead is too high?  I have tried with driver settings of `driver.memory=9G` and `driver.memoryOverhead=1G`  Or do you think it should just be 9G and 900M?  Or should this be the whole master nodes memory(memory=27G and memoryOverhead=3G)?

Comment: `or better containerize spark nodes since allocated driver memory,` What do you mean by this?

Comment: available memory is 30gb
and you are setting 
"spark.executor.cores": "5",
"spark.executors.memory": "8G",
"spark.driver.cores": "5",
"spark.driver.memory": "7G",

if you set as
"spark.driver.cores": "1", 
"spark.executor.cores": "1",
without changing memoryOverHead it should work. if still fails you may try commenting out some part of spark code to make sure its not code memory allocation related issue

Comment: If i am reducing the number of cores per executor, should I increase the number of total instances and parallelism as well or leave that as is? I don't think removing code is viable for me, my errors happen ~5 hours into my run, if it were code allocation related, what should I adjust to fix it.  Should i increase my executor/driver memory?

Comment: I would just try after reducing the core and make sure it runs successfully, if fails i would go and comment out code blocks potentially allocating more memory that causes spark to crash and build and try with new build without changing the spark configuration

Comment: You mention 1000's of files but not how many thousand. Are your files equally distributed ? Could it be possible that you are running out of memory due to too many files located on 1 node ?

Comment: About 8000, total size around 1TB uncompressed. It should be spread over multiple nodes, i just specify a top level folder and wild card read all files within, that should distribute evenly I believe. I wouldn't expect all files to be in memory at once, i dont collect or anything. I read into rdd, map the rdd, convert to data frame, select data, and transform columns and types, and write data.